Is it possible to export layers while maintaining reflections? (EEVEE)
I have this shot here that I am separating into view layers and exporting as separate PNG sequences for compositing.

The background with the mirror is also on its own layer, and it would be ideal for comp if I was able to keep the reflections of the three guys in the mirror in that layer.
Right now the layers are:

Desk/Props/Lamp
Agent Man 1
Man in hoodie
Agent Man 2
BG with Mirror

In other words, I'm wondering how I can export layer 5, while keeping the reflections from the 4 other layers?
Does anyone have any ideas for how to achieve this?

If you don't plan to do the comp in Blender you could use the File Output Node in the Copositor area to export the needed information (mirror). To select just the mirror infos, you can use a cryptomatte to mask it and save it as a PNG with transparency to a seperate file.
Are you using Grease Pencil? Then don't forget to mask the grease pencil object also.
The best is to compose it directly in Blender. The most challenges can be achieved there.

Thanks @ChristophWerner! Cryptomatte looks promising, but its still not quite what im looking for. Here is what I have right now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TB5EVJf7iysrj71Uf7ET-Yq4KRvdZzTT/view?usp=sharing
Is it possible to not have the matte cut outs in the image? Ideally I just want the Mirror object, with the reflections, and no other objects or cutouts in the way.

@ChristophWerner is there maybe a way to bake the reflection into the mirror material and have it run like an image texture with a movie clip?

I ask it different: What are you trying to achieve for the final result? Blurring the mirror content or something different?

@ChristophWerner Yes I want to blur the mirror and background (among other things) in after effects where I am doing my compositing. I can try to use the cryptomatte to make a png sequence for just the mirror but the cut outs would create odd blurs and mattes when combined with the rest of my composition. Do you know of any way I can render the mirror, with the reflections of the characters, but without the characters being there in the foreground?
I've also considered rendering out a separate shot from the perspective of the mirror, but I am wondering if there is an easier way.

You could save just the mirror objects like the example below.
If you have Grease Pencil Outlines, you have to render them into a seperate View Layer. Before doing this you have to bake the Grease Pencil Outlines first and place them into an own Collection. Then you can hide the other collections in the Grease Pencil View Layer. The Outlines then can be composed later at the top of all layers.
Hope that helps.


If you need control for the depth of field effect later in After Effects, you can also render out the mist pass in Blender. It can be used as z-buffer information in After Effects I guess.

I'd still like to find a way to do this without having the hold outs and cut outs. Ive been playing around and this is the closest I've gotten:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ORoiWderv23CnjDm1k67bfBscuXbhNCb/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16xkN0Rl7Qo5HzAmxQKyKjpJdR3-7f9Rt/view?usp=sharing
This still isn't ideal because of the holes in the reflections but might work for what I'm trying to do in comp. Do you know of any way I could do this while maintaining the entire reflection?

I would still do it in Blender. It's the fastest way. And without complications. You can add the outlines also into the mirror if you invest some more time into grease pencils outline techniques.



